# Flutter: draw icon based on string icon api

Tags: flutter, image, widget, icons

I receive icons name in JSON. Icon name is compatible with flutter icon name. So for example if I receive:

```json
{ "icon":"rotate_90_degrees_ccw"}
```

I should draw on screen this icon: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons/rotate_90_degrees_ccw-constant.html

I know, that I do my own map, where key is string name of icon, and value can be icon, but I should predict each case, but I expect almost every icon from collection: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Icons-class.html

So... how to do it in the most efficient way? How to just convert string into flutter Icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of answers recommending conversion of `String` to `Map<String,IconData>` .

i think that would be ok in case of you have limited number of string icons, because that way requires hardcoding.

```
String rotationIcon = "rotate_90_degrees_ccw";

Map<String,IconData> icons = {rotationIcon: Icons.rotate_90_degrees_ccw}

Icon icon = Icon(icons[rotationIcon]);
```

if you have 100 possible icons that may be returned by the `API`, you have to hardcode them in that map.

btw, there are packages that directly convert `strings` to `icons`, example :  [string2icon](https://pub.dev/packages/string_2_icon)

these packages were mainly built dependent on icons hardcoding.

**Second choice**

What a perfered way, if your `API` returns the code of the icon rather than its name, it will become easy and direct.

```
IconData rotateIcon = IconData(0xe53e, fontFamily: 'MaterialIcons');

Icon(rotateIcon);
```

`0xe53e` is the icon code that the `API` returns.

at last, I hope all headings are open for you.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I hoped, that exist any 3rd solution, but  thank YOu for explain, I choose 1st option from Your post, thank You!

Comment: @sosnus u r wlcm